# Html2Canvas delay in rendering images and not in a sequence

Tags: jquery, delay, html2canvas

I am having problems with Html2canvas render as i want to take multiple screenshots of an image and send the same to the selected contacts in a sequence but Html2canvas is rendering images in a delayed and unsequential way, which in return is not able to send the image to corresponding selected contact. Below is my code it is running successfully but the delay and unsequential output is creating a lot of problem.

```
function printCards(calle, eventID){
    var cards = new Array();

    var checkboxArray = $("input[name='contactsParty']:checked");

    $('#inviteContactName').html($(checkboxArray[0]).parent().prev().children('label').text());

        //  iterating selected checkboxes for invitation
        checkboxArray.each(function(index, value){


            //  getting name of next contact selected
            var name = $(checkboxArray[index+1]).parents().eq(1).find('label').text();


            //  Getting invitation card
            var invitationCard;
            $.when(invitationCard = getImage(name)).promise().done(function(){
                //  saving the printed invitation
                cards.push(invitationCard);
            });

        });

    return cards;   

}

//  printing invitation card with contact name
function getImage(name){

    var invitationCard = new Image();


        html2canvas($("#invitationData"), {
//          logging : true,
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                //  For image`enter code here`
                var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
//              ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
//              ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
                ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

                var convertedImage;
                $.when(convertedImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg')).promise().done(function(){
                    invitationCard.src = convertedImage;
                    $('#inviteContactName').html(name);
                });  
//              setTimeout(function (){}, 500);
            }

        });

    return invitationCard;

}
```

Comment: @Niklas plz have a look on this topic......

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ? , create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ? Tried returning `invitationCard` as a resolved jQuery.Deferred within `img` `invitationCard` `load` event ?

Comment: yup tried evrithing.....used jQuery.Deferred but still delay n unsequential execution...

Comment: _"yup tried evrithing.....used jQuery.Deferred but still delay n unsequential execution... "_ Can create stacksnippets, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: @guest271314 the module in which this code is being used is very complex...so i wont b able to create a fiddle or a stacksnippet.....this code is working fine in firefox but in chrome it is unsequential.

Comment: @Abhishek I suggest you take a look at my answer, I've had the same problems as you and it wasn't related to html2canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in the upcoming release of html2canvas, as this issue has been raised earlier many times at developer's site. you just have to wait for the final release for production or you can try the beta version of it.

P.S - current release is for development purposes only and not for production.
(This should be a comment but i dont have that much reputation.)

Comment: This doesn't look like an issue in Html2Canvas, do you have any source for it?

Answer (score 3):

This shouldn't be an issue with Html2Canvas, rather the way you're loading base64 encoded images isn't using a callback.

Also, you're using promises in a "wonky" way, you're waiting on events that aren't asynchronous. So no wonder everything is in the wrong order.

`canvas.toDataURL` is executed synchronously, while assigning an `Image` object `src` **is asynchronous**.

As per the [MDN page about images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images)

```
var img = new Image();   // Create new img element
img.onload = function() {
    // image is loaded now
}
img.src = 'myImage.png'; // Set source path NOTE: this can be a base64 dataURL
```

Also, your `getImage()` function **is not returning a `$.deferred()`**, this means `$.when()` will **execute immediately**.

Here's some code that should fix it, I'm creating a promise that will be resolved **when the image is loaded**

```
function getImage(name){
    var promise = $.deferred();
    var invitationCard = new Image();
        html2canvas($("#invitationData"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
                var convertedImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
                invitationCard.onload = function () {
                    // here loading is done, resolve our promise
                    $('#inviteContactName').html(name);
                    // pass the loaded image along with the promise
                    promise.resolve(invitationCard);
                }
                invitationCard.src = convertedImage;
            }
        });
    return promise;
}
```

In your code calling `getImage()`

```
checkboxArray.each(function(index, value){
            //  getting name of next contact selected
            var name = $(checkboxArray[index+1]).parents().eq(1).find('label').text();
            //  Getting invitation card
            var invitationCard = getImage(name);
            $.when(invitationCard).done(function(image){
                //  promise is resolved, image is loaded and can be used
                cards.push(image);
            });
        });
```

I couldn't test your code specifically but I've had to manage plenty of images that had to be loaded after a series of `canvas.toDataURL()`. 
My problem when doing things in orderd was always the `onload` callback for `Image` objects, while Html2Canvas has worked correctly so far for me.

Also, the reason you see different behaviours on different browsers is due to the speed of execution and/or image caching. If the browser can load the image before you use it all goes well, but you shouldn't assume that, **always use `onload` when creating images**.

Comment: the getImage(name) function is returning the image generated but according to your answer the instead of image a deferred object is returned so i wont be able to get the image generated to my cards array. I realy appreciated your answer but it is not according to my requrement as i am storing the generated images in an array for further use and that too in the sequence of the checkbox selected.

Comment: @Abhishek if that's what you need you can just pass the loaded image along with the promise, check the code, I've updated the `resolve` and `done` parts

Comment: Realy sorry to inform you....code is not according to the requirement I tested in every possible way....it is generating duplicate images.

Comment: @Abhishek are you getting two images in the cards array? Or is it getting printed twice? From the code you posted it shouldn't happen, maybe it could be other code not shown here.

Comment: the scenario is on the image name that is supplied to getImage() has to be displayed. After applying your code the name supplied once is getting displayed multiple times. Which should not happen, one name on one image.

Comment: Try removing `$('#inviteContactName').html(name);`, I left that in because it was in your original code

Comment: $('#inviteContactName').html(name); this line of code is changing the name for the card to print. so i cannot remove it.

Comment: Are you sure the name isn't already in your card's html? Html2canvas will print all the text already present

Comment: i am changing the name in the html dynamically after successful render of the image with the previous name for html2canvas to process next image on next iteration of the each function. My original code is doing the proposed work but it is not in a sequence in chrome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83940/discussion-between-sosdoc-and-abhishek).